# Play Audio from receiver website

Tags: audio, google-cast, chromecast

I'm trying to get my receiver to play an mp3 file hosted on the server with the following function

```
playSound_: function(mp3_file) {
  var snd = new Audio("audio/" + mp3_file);
  snd.play();
},
```

However, most of the time it doesn't play and when it does play, it's delayed. When I load the receiver in my local browser, however, it works fine.

What's the correct way to play audio on the receiver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either a MediaElement tag or Web Audio API. Simplest is probably a MediaElement.

Comment: Would you be willing to provide some sample code or a link to more information? Is a MediaElement tag the same thing as an `audio` tag? That's what I tried in the original implementation I provided in the question. Thanks!

Comment: If you know the audio file that you want to play, just add <audio src="http://***/*.mp3" autoplay/> to the body of your receiver. I haven't tried it but I _think_ it would work. If you want to control the playback (for example don't want to autoplay), then simply use the api's that are available to you to play that. You can see this [site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video) for the HTML5 apis that you can use

Comment: Essentially, my js code is creating an `audio` element, but not adding it to the DOM. This is the API I'm using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement. It works on my local Chrome browser (OSX - 31.0.1650.63), but only intermittently on the Chromecast.

Comment: Did you try adding the audio tag as I had in my earlier comment?

Comment: I ended up using an `audio` tag and then after the `window load` event I can play it